# filtering (moire / banding(?)) problem when downsizing video

Tags: export, transforms, video-sequence-editor, video, artifacts

During video editing, I noticed this issue when downsampling 4K video to HD.
I tried different filtering methods, but the problem remains.
Is there any setting or workaround to get rid of it? thx
[image: comparison davinci resolve vs blender filtering]

Comment: I think we should see the setup in the video editor. So the blend file would be helpful, even without the clips itself. Use [https://blend-exchange.com/](https://blend-exchange.com/)

Comment: sure, here it is with a single frame. you might need to unpack the files first and relink them, since blender does not support packing VSE strips. thank you for your time

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=9sBp9EMy" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9sBp9EMy/)